# Can't access System.Numerics from within a Xamarin Android project

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, nuget, biginteger, .net-standard

I am attempting to use the `System.Numerics.BigInteger` struct from within a Xamarin.Android project, but the `System.Numerics` namespace is not accessible, despite having installed the latest version of the Nuget package that claims to contain `BigInteger`:

[image]

**Update**: If I create a .NET Standard 1.6 class library, I can reference `BigInteger` from within it. I find it hard to understand why `BigInteger` is not accessible from with the Android project, which also references .NET Standard 1.6. I can also reference the class library from the Xamarin.Android project and build the solution, but if the Android project tries to access any method in the class library that returns a `BigInteger`, the compile complains:

```
The type 'BigInteger' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Numerics, Version=2.0.5.0 ... '.
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: The error message already tells you what is wrong. You must *reference* the assembly that contains the `BigInteger` data type, e.g.  `'System.Numerics, Version=2.0.5.0 ... '`. Did you actually do that?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: I referenced System.Runtime.Numerics which, according to the image above, provides support for BigInteger. There is no System.Numerics Nuget package listed, so where do I find this DLL in order to reference it?